# Why is undef turning into an empty string?

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h;
my $undef = undef;
$h{''}='test2';
$h{$undef} = 'test';

print Dumper (\%h);
```

Creates the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '' => 'test'
        };
```

Why is this happening?
I have Perl 5.12.3.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All hash keys are strings.  Non-string values used as hash keys are coerced to strings, and `undef` becomes `''` in that context.

Comment: Thank you chaos. Is this somewhere in the Perl-documentation?

Comment: @Birdy: 'man perldata' (aka http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) defines hashes as "unordered collections of scalar values indexed by their associated string key".  Everything else follows from keys being strings, Perl's automatic type promotion and the behavior of undef.